# Unable to Import Frameworks/Pods into xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I have an issue with xcode where if I try to insert a pod or framework into my project it doesn't see to link. For instance, I added the `CoreLocation` framework as well as the `Firebase/Core` pods. In both instances when I go to add:

`Import Firebase
Import CoreLocation`

the suggestions which appear do not find the desired Framework/Pod to import in my app delegate which leads me to believe there is some sort of linking error. I am further convinced of this because when I try to type things in such as `CLLocation Manager` and try to run them I get a "build failed" error with the debugger stating "use of unresolved identifier x".

I'm new to stack overflow so hopefully this question isn't too wordy or too general please let me know if any further information is needed.

Comment: How did you insert pod to your project?

Comment: I used the terminal command `pod init` went into the created podfile, inserted `pod Firebase/Core` and `pod Firebase/Database` and then went back into terminal and ran command `pod install`. All pods appeared green during installation which leads me to believe theres some sort of error im experiencing in Xcode

Comment: The thing is when i go to `import <framework>` or `import <pod>` the suggestions don't show up for them which makes me believe that Xcode isn't even registering that they are there.

Comment: Are you open <youproject.xcodeproj> after it or what?

Comment: I opened <myproject.xcodeworkspace>

Comment: I have a feeling it's not just a pods installation issue because even with `coreLocation` framework it appears as if the framework was not found

Comment: I also made sure that `Target Membership` is selected as well. I haven't seen anyone ever run into this issue

Comment: 1) Right Click on yourfile.swift

2) Select Show File Inspector

3) On Right side panel, look at Target Membership

4) Add your class to target by check the box :)

Answer (score 0):

first, check the pod version and update to the latest version. Then, try building the project multiple times, if nothing happened, remove `pod 'Firebase/Core'` and do `pod install` then re-add this line again and do `pod install` again.
One of the things I've noticed above is that you're not using single quotation marks around the framework name in the podfile.